# How do I know the project is targeted for Windows Phone Emulator when it is being built?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, build

In my Windows Phone project for SDK 7.1 I want to conditionally include a file:

```
<Content Include="MyFile.jpg" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
```

all good, but the condition is not perfect. I want the file included only when the project is being built for the Windows Phone Emulator. The target is selected with a dropdown in Visual Studio:

[image]

I've looked through [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) and can't find a suitable variable that would be populated with the target name.

Which build variable do I use to detect that the project is being targeted for the Windows Phone Emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I think that for the emulator [this property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.devicename%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) will be equal to "Emulator" or something like that (you may check its exact value by launching the app on the emulator and use that value).

Comment: This property is available at runtime, not at compile time